# To compare two elements(string type) in XSLT?

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

i am new to XSLT ,can any one please suggest to me how to compare two elements coming from xml as string their values are:

```
<OU_NAME>Vision Operations</OU_NAME> --XML code
<OU_ADDR1>90 Fifth Avenue</OU_ADDR1> --XML code

<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="OU_NAME='OU_ADDR1'"> --comparing two elements coming from XML
        <!--remove if  adrees already contain  operating unit name
            <xsl:value-of select="OU_NAME"/> <fo:block/>-->
        <xsl:if test="OU_ADDR1 !='' ">
            <xsl:value-of select="OU_ADDR1"/>
            <fo:block/>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="LE_ADDR2 !='' ">
            <xsl:value-of select="OU_ADDR2"/>
            <fo:block/>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="LE_ADDR3 !='' ">
            <xsl:value-of select="OU_ADDR3"/>
            <fo:block/>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="OU_TOWN_CITY !=''">
            <xsl:value-of select="OU_TOWN_CITY"/>,
            <fo:leader leader-pattern="space" leader-length="2.0pt"/>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:value-of select="OU_REGION2"/>
        <fo:leader leader-pattern="space" leader-length="3.0pt"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="OU_POSTALCODE"/>
        <fo:block/>
        <xsl:value-of select="OU_COUNTRY"/>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:value-of select="OU_NAME"/>
        <fo:block/>
        <xsl:if test="OU_ADDR1 !='' ">
            <xsl:value-of select="OU_ADDR1"/>
            <fo:block/>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="LE_ADDR2 !='' ">
            <xsl:value-of select="OU_ADDR2"/>
            <fo:block/>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="LE_ADDR3 !='' ">
            <xsl:value-of select="OU_ADDR3"/>
            <fo:block/>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="OU_TOWN_CITY !=''">
            <xsl:value-of select="OU_TOWN_CITY"/>,
            <fo:leader leader-pattern="space" leader-length="2.0pt"/>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:value-of select="OU_REGION2"/>
        <fo:leader leader-pattern="space" leader-length="3.0pt"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="OU_POSTALCODE"/>
        <fo:block/>
        <xsl:value-of select="OU_COUNTRY"/>
    </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

Answer (score 42):

**First of all, the provided long code**:

```
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="OU_NAME='OU_ADDR1'">   --comparing two elements coming from XML             
            <!--remove if  adrees already contain  operating unit name <xsl:value-of select="OU_NAME"/> <fo:block/>-->
            <xsl:if test="OU_ADDR1 !='' ">
                <xsl:value-of select="OU_ADDR1"/>
                <fo:block/>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test="LE_ADDR2 !='' ">
                <xsl:value-of select="OU_ADDR2"/>
                <fo:block/>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test="LE_ADDR3 !='' ">
                <xsl:value-of select="OU_ADDR3"/>
                <fo:block/>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test="OU_TOWN_CITY !=''">
                <xsl:value-of select="OU_TOWN_CITY"/>,
                <fo:leader leader-pattern="space" leader-length="2.0pt"/>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:value-of select="OU_REGION2"/>
            <fo:leader leader-pattern="space" leader-length="3.0pt"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="OU_POSTALCODE"/>
            <fo:block/>
            <xsl:value-of select="OU_COUNTRY"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="OU_NAME"/>
            <fo:block/>
            <xsl:if test="OU_ADDR1 !='' ">
                <xsl:value-of select="OU_ADDR1"/>
                <fo:block/>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test="LE_ADDR2 !='' ">
                <xsl:value-of select="OU_ADDR2"/>
                <fo:block/>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test="LE_ADDR3 !='' ">
                <xsl:value-of select="OU_ADDR3"/>
                <fo:block/>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test="OU_TOWN_CITY !=''">
                <xsl:value-of select="OU_TOWN_CITY"/>,
                <fo:leader leader-pattern="space" leader-length="2.0pt"/>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:value-of select="OU_REGION2"/>
            <fo:leader leader-pattern="space" leader-length="3.0pt"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="OU_POSTALCODE"/>
            <fo:block/>
            <xsl:value-of select="OU_COUNTRY"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
```

**is equivalent to this, much shorter code**:

```
<xsl:if test="not(OU_NAME='OU_ADDR1)'">
              <xsl:value-of select="OU_NAME"/>
        </xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test="OU_ADDR1 !='' ">
                <xsl:value-of select="OU_ADDR1"/>
                <fo:block/>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test="LE_ADDR2 !='' ">
                <xsl:value-of select="OU_ADDR2"/>
                <fo:block/>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test="LE_ADDR3 !='' ">
                <xsl:value-of select="OU_ADDR3"/>
                <fo:block/>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test="OU_TOWN_CITY !=''">
                <xsl:value-of select="OU_TOWN_CITY"/>,
                <fo:leader leader-pattern="space" leader-length="2.0pt"/>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:value-of select="OU_REGION2"/>
            <fo:leader leader-pattern="space" leader-length="3.0pt"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="OU_POSTALCODE"/>
            <fo:block/>
            <xsl:value-of select="OU_COUNTRY"/>
```

**Now, to your question:**

> how to compare two elements coming
>   from xml as string

In Xpath 1.0 strings can be compared only for equality (or inequality), using the operator `=` and the function `not()` together with the operator `=`.

```
$str1 = $str2
```

evaluates to `true()` exactly when the string `$str1` is equal to the string `$str2`.

```
not($str1 = $str2)
```

evaluates to `true()` exactly when the string `$str1` is not equal to the string `$str2`.

There is also the `!=` operator. It generally should be avoided because it has anomalous behavior whenever one of its operands is a node-set.

**Now, the rules for comparing two element nodes are similar**:

```
$el1 = $el2
```

evaluates to `true()` exactly when the string value of `$el1` is equal to the string value of `$el2`.

```
not($el1 = $el2)
```

evaluates to `true()` exactly when the string value of `$el1` is not equal to the string value of `$el2`.

However, if one of the operands of `=` is a node-set, then

```
 $ns = $str
```

evaluates to `true()` exactly when there is at least one node in the node-set `$ns1`, whose string value is equal to the string `$str`

```
$ns1 = $ns2
```

evaluates to `true()` exactly when there is at least one node in the node-set `$ns1`, whose string value is equal to the string value of some node from `$ns2`

**Therefore, the expression**:

```
OU_NAME='OU_ADDR1'
```

evaluates to `true()` only when there is at least one element child of the current node that is named `OU_NAME` and whose string value is the string 'OU_ADDR1'.

**This is obviously not what you want!**

Most probably you want:

```
OU_NAME=OU_ADDR1
```

This expression evaluates to `true` exactly there is at least one `OU_NAME` child of the current node and one `OU_ADDR1` child of the current node with the same string value.

**Finally**, in XPath 2.0, strings can be compared also using the value comparison operators `lt`, `le`, `eq`, `gt`, `ge` and the inherited from XPath 1.0 general comparison operator `=`.

Trying to evaluate a value comparison operator when one or both of its arguments is a sequence of more than one item results in error.